# How to bind caliburn.micro view model to WP8 LongListSelector control?

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro, longlistselector

Is there a way to automagically bind a Caliburn.Micro view model to the Windows Phone 8 `LongListSelector` control and auto-wire the SelectedItem property?

Answer (score 3):

If i understand your question correctly, then you want normal Caliburn.Micro conventions to be applied to the [`LongListSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control.

I don't work with Windows Phone development but i think it can be done by calling the following line of code in the `Configure()` method of the bootstrapper.

`ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<LongListSelector>(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged");`

This code tells Caliburn.Micro to use the `ItemsSource` property whenever it a finds a named *(e.g. x:Name="myList")* `LongListSelector` and to use the `SelectedItem` whenever a LongListSelector element is passed in the parameter list of an action message, and finally it uses the `SelectionChanged` event to fire action messages by default.

Comment: The list binds, but the SelectedItem isn't executed?

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt What do you mean by the `SelectedItem isn't executed ? If you mean it is not bound then you are correct because the `SelectedItem` isn't a dependency property, so you can't apply binding to it. What you can do is attach a message handler on the `LongListSelector` and use that handler to call a method on the view-model of the list to notify it when the `SelectedItem` changes.

Comment: This gets part way there. It doesn't seem to take care of using a user control automatically for the items being displayed, where as it is automatic for the ListBox.