# Caliburn.Micro cannot bind to LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

Windows phone 8 with Caliburn.Micro 2.0.1 cannot bind to LongListSelector. For Caliburn tries to bind items to Visibility property.
Here is XAML

```
<phone:LongListSelector
    x:Name="Items"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}">
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

and view model property is pretty basic:

```
    IObservableCollection<Item> _Items;
    public IObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set 
        {
            _Items = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Items);
        }
    }

    public class Item : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name); }
        }
    }
```

Here is the debug output

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 'MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection`1[Checklists.ViewModels.ItemsPageViewModel+Item]' (type 'Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection`1[CLS.ViewModels.ItemsPageViewModel+Item]'); BindingExpression: Path='Items' DataItem='CLS.ViewModels.ItemsPageViewModel' (HashCode=38524289); target element is 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' (Name='Items'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'System.Windows.Visibility').. System.InvalidOperationException: Can't convert type Caliburn.Micro.BindableCollection`1[CLS.ViewModels.ItemsPageViewModel+Item] to type System.Windows.Visibility.
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.Create(Type sourceType, Type targetType, Boolean targetToSource)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.EnsureConverter(Type sourceType, Type targetType)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertToTarget(Object value).
```

Answer (score 2):

The convention you're trying to make use of here is the one Caliburn.Micro has set up for `ItemsControl`, unfortunately it doesn't appear that [LongListSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector(v=vs.105).aspx) inherits from `ItemsControl`. It's odd that it doesn't so you'd assume everything would just work.

A very basic convention for `LongListSelector` could be added with the following

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<LongListSelector>(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty, "DataContext", "Loaded");
```

which would be called in your `Bootstrapper`. Note that this convention does't set up a default `ItemTemplate` that the one for `ItemsSource` does.

**Edit:**
The first property is used for property binding conventions, if you have a property matching the `x:Name` then this is the property bound to.

The second is the parameter property, if you refer to the element as a parameter in a message such as `cm:Message.Attach="DoStuff(Items)"` then what property is used.

The third is event that fires the action if there is one attached.

The one mentioned in the comments

```
ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<LongListSelector>(LongListSelector.Items‌​SourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged");
```

is better in that if you're using any of the other features that require the second two properties. The first convention simply uses boiler plate parameters.

Comment: After this convention item binding works but selected item property is not bound. What else is missing?

Comment: It doesn't appear that LongListSelector.SelectedItem is a dependency property so it can't actually be bound to, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031964/trouble-binding-longlistselector-selecteditem-to-mvvm-property for more detail.

Comment: oh... just one more exceptional case :)

Comment: Yeah sadly there's a lot of controls that are exceptional cases.

Comment: @NigelSampson I've found another solution: `ConventionManager.AddElementConvention<LongListSelector>(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty, "SelectedItem", "SelectionChanged");`. Can you tell what's difference to your way? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905342/how-to-bind-caliburn-micro-view-model-to-wp8-longlistselector-control

Comment: I've added comments about the second convention to the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

which makes sense its not a bug since LongListSelector isn't in the ConventionManager list of controls for windows Phone.  You would have to add it as a custom convention for that control.  Otherwise just bind normally...

Comment: So it is not a bug. How can I add this control to the list?